# TypeError: Razorpay is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to integrate Razorpay with node typescript. But getting this error. I think it seems to be with the const variable `razor`.
Thank you in advance

```
 import * as Razorpay from 'razorpay';


const razor = new Razorpay({
  key_id: 'xxxxxxxxx',
  key_secret: 'xxxxxxxxx',
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like in example below:

```
import Razorpay from 'razorpay';
```

Then you will get access to the constructor.

```
const razor = new Razorpay({
  key_id: 'xxxxxxxxx',
  key_secret: 'xxxxxxxxx',
});
```